# why this event cannot output the expected result?

Tags: c#, events

I am making some practices about the 'event' programming in C#. After duplicating a sample program from the textbook, it cannot work as this book said. I checked few times and can not still find where the error was. I will appreciate it if someone can help me figure it out.

```
using System;
delegate void Handler();

class Incrementer
{
    public event Handler CountedADozen;

public void DoCount()
 {
    for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
        if (i % 12 == 0 && CountedADozen != null)
            CountedADozen();
 }
}

class Dozens
{
public int DozensCount { get; private set; }
public Dozens(Incrementer incrementer)
 {
    DozensCount = 0;


    Incrementer.CountedADozen += IncrementDozensCount;
 }
void IncrementDozensCount()
 {
    DozensCount++;
 }
}

class program
{
static void Main()
 {
    Incrementer incrementer = new Incrementer();
    Dozens dozensCounter = new Dozens(incrementer);

    incrementer.DoCount();
    Console.WriteLine("Number of dozens={0}", dozensCounter.DozensCount);
 }
}
```

The expected result should be 8 as you can see but my result is 0.

Comment: Don't use bitmaps to post text data like code. Post text.

Comment: The reason you get downvote is the code shared via image. Please share your code in the question itself. What do you mean by not working?

Comment: As for your bug, you are creating a new `Incrementer()` in your `Dozens()` constructor, instead of using the one that was passed in. Don't do that. Use the one that was passed in, and then the `DozensCount` you're reading will be the same one you're writing.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya: _"The only reason you get downvote"_ -- well, I wouldn't say that. It's _a_ reason. But, the question also isn't very useful. It's basically just a simple logic/typographic mistake that is unlikely to helpful to anyone else in the future, and which could have been resolved by some basic debugging on the OP's part.

Comment: @PeterDuniho agreed.

Comment: Images of your code are useless. See [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of the many reasons why you should NOT post images of code. Code is text, and it can be copied and pasted (and properly formatted) into your question much more easily than posting an image. Please [edit] your post to include that code properly in your question.

Comment: Lowercase i for incrementer for your event listener incrementer.CountedADozen += IncrementDozensCount;

Comment: The issues have been resolved, thank for u guys' advice. I am new to this forum, i will improve some question-posting problems next time.

Comment: @Xela Of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two incrementers, one is being passed into your constructor(And is not being used) and the del incrementer is listening but DoCount is never being called on it.

Remove the del incrementer and replace del.CountedADozen with incrementer.CountedADozen since that is the incrementer you want to use in this design pattern.

Comment: I have done this but the debugger said that "an object reference is required for the non -static field, method...". I did it before i crated a new object of Incrementer.

Comment: Lowercase i for incrementer for your event listener incrementer.CountedADozen += IncrementDozensCount;

Comment: i've found where the issue is. Thanks for ur answer and patience. :)